Como solucionar "Consider defining a bean of type .... in your configuration"?
estoy creando una ApiRest con Spring, tengo el siguiente mensaje en consola al ejecutar el proyecto.
No entiendo, mi clase de AuthenticationController estan en la misma ruta, todo esta en su lugar
PD: Estoy usando el IDE IntelliJ Idea
Field authService in com.stockproject.ranz.controller.AuthenticationController required a bean of type 'com.stockproject.ranz.services.authentication.AuthService' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.stockproject.ranz.services.authentication.AuthService' in your configuration.

Este es mi codigo de AuthService:
Aun asi agrego la Annotation @Service y sigue dando el mismo error.
    package com.stockproject.ranz.services.authentication;

import com.stockproject.ranz.dto.SignupRequestDTO;
import com.stockproject.ranz.dto.UserDto;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public interface AuthService {

   UserDto signupUser(SignupRequestDTO signupRequestDTO);

    Boolean presentByUsername(String userName);
}

Codigo de AuthenticationController:
package com.stockproject.ranz.controller;

import com.stockproject.ranz.dto.SignupRequestDTO;
import com.stockproject.ranz.dto.UserDto;

import com.stockproject.ranz.services.authentication.AuthService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class AuthenticationController {

    @Autowired
    private AuthService authService;

    @PostMapping("/user/signup")
    public ResponseEntity<?> signupUser(@RequestBody SignupRequestDTO signupRequestDTO) {
        if (authService.presentByUsername(signupRequestDTO.getUserName())) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>( "Usuario ya existente!", HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE);
        }
        UserDto createdUser = authService.signupUser(signupRequestDTO);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(createdUser, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}


¿Y donde está la implementación de AuthService? Ahí es donde deberías poner @Service para que lo instancie Spring.

@RubioRic Gracias.. no me percate que faltaba implementar en la Clase.
